# I would like to know how to create a custom dialog box that rises when button gets clicked n that

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to create a custom dialog box that rises when button gets clicked n that box should be beside the the button...please help me out brothers

Comment: refer this link http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap model

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I Googled it n I got bootstrap code n I tried to copy it n xecute it but I didnt gotta custom dialog box...

Comment: thanx for the help and please let me ask one more thing...this dialog box should be opened when a button fires must be beside the button...can u please show me the way to find it...thanx again backtrack